# QGIS 3.0.3 topology checker to find gaps between polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-3, topology

When using QGIS 2.x I have used Topology checker to find gaps between polygons, crossing lines and duplicated points/vertex. I also liked that it shoved a list of errors where I could zoom into each error to fix it.

In version 3.0.3 I see that topology checker is running automatically and tells me at once when I put two point on top of each other.

How can I make it check for gaps? Is there somewhere to set the topology rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer maybe late, but for QGIS 3.4.1, which I expect it was available in QGIS 3.0.3, you can define topological rule to check for gaps using the following steps:

- Go to `Vector -> Topology Checker`
- A panel will be opened

[image]

- Click on the `Configure` in the red box above to define a rule
- Select the layer you want to check its topology -> Under Rule select `Must not have gaps` `->` Click on `Add Rule ->` Click `OK`:

[image]

- The Configuration window will be like this:

[image]

- Click on Validate all to to check if there is a gap in the layer

[image]

- Click on the row and it will highlight the gap location

[image]

Comment: I noticed in QGIS 3.6, the topology plugin is installed but not loaded by default, you need to go into installed plugins and tick it.

Comment: For some reason, this plugin does not find gaps. I created a trial polygon layer with bad geometry, overlaps, and gaps. It only found bad geometry and overlaps. Does not flag gaps. Is there a tolerance I have to set? Using QGIS 3.8.2